# Vim: don't move cursor when I scroll (via mouse)

Tags: vim, macvim

When I scroll up/down and the cursor is in the visible region, it stays at that place.

However, when I scroll and the cursor reaches the edge (bottom or top), it will move along with my scrolling so that it always stays in the visible region.

I don't want that. I don't want that the scrolling changes the cursor at all. How can I disable that?

Comment: Similar question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680456/vim-keep-cursor-location-while-scrolling

Comment: This behavior is actually what I want in my vim - i.e. when I turn the scroll wheel, I want the screen to move (right now it's the cursor that moves).  Do you know how can I do that?  What's your vim configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That unfortunately cannot be changed. Vim's implementation cannot handle that the cursor is outside the currently visible viewport; that's why it has to move. As a lot of plugins also use this assumption, this is unlikely to change.

Comment: Do you know if there is maybe a fork of Vim (or MacVim) which can do that? Or maybe some plugin which can emulate that behavior somehow (it would need to catch the scroll events, not sure if that is possible)?

Comment: I could imagine a veeeery cumbersome plugin implementation (basically a display rewrite in Vimscript), but (as I said), this assumption is inherent in the implementation, so a lot of things would break / need to be adapted.